# VB.NET shell open PDF to a specific page

Tags: vb.net, pdf, shell

How do I open a pdf file to a specific page within the pdf.

Below is a link to some of the open parameters when using command line:

[PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Page 5 of the document you linked shows a parameter for this.  Is that not working for you?

(Also, note that this is only for documents opened with Adobe Acrobat.  The arguments are for the application, not the document.  So if you don't control/know your users' environments then it may not work for all users.)

Answer (score 1):

The following will code will open up text.pdf to page 2:

```
Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
p.Verb = "Open"
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
p.UseShellExecute = True
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 7.0\Acrobat\acrobat.exe", "/A " & Chr(34) & "page=2" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & "C:\TEMP\DeleteME\test.pdf" & Chr(34))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Page Number

Dim MyPageNumber As Integer

'Acrobat Reader Path

Dim AcrobatReaderPath As String = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

'Pdf File Name

Dim PdfFileName As String = "Egypt.pdf"

'Open Page

Shell(AcrobatReaderPath & " /A Page=" & MyPageNumber & " " & Application.StartupPath & "\" & PdfFileName, AppWinStyle.MaximizedFocus)
```